# Get latest git tags on Gitlab CI/CD pipeline

Tags: git, continuous-integration, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I want to set up a CI/CD pipelines in Gitlab that can read the latest tag and get that last tag to increment my next version application. I came with this configuration:

```
stages:
  - version

calculate_version:
  image:
    name: alpine/git:latest
    entrypoint: [""]
  stage: version
  script:
    - VERSION=$(git tag);test -z "$VERSION" && echo "no version tag found" && exit 1
    - CMDLINE="$VERSION";
    - echo $VERSION
    - echo $CMDLINE > cmdline
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - cmdline
```

But i get no tags listed there on $VERSION. Its look like Gitlab not passing the tags on the repository. However if I create and push a new tag, it shows just that new tag, not all tag list I expected.

Is this the behaviour of the GitLab ci/cd? If yes, how can I get all of the tags in my repo inside the pipeline?

Comment: [`$CI_COMMIT_TAG`](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/README.html)?

Comment: `$CI_COMMIT_TAG` is [The commit tag name. Present only when building tags.](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/predefined_variables.html#predefined-environment-variables-reference), it returns no tag if I just committing without tag.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can obtain tags using [Gitlab API](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/api/tags.html#list-project-repository-tags)

By default, results are ordered by the last updated tags, so if you want to get the last one, you can modify your script block like this:

```
script:
  - VERSION=$(curl -Ss --request GET --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: <REPLACE_BY_A_VARIABLE>" "https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/${CI_PROJECT_ID}/repository/tags" | jq -r '.[0] | .name')
  - test -z "$VERSION" && echo "no version tag found" && exit 1
```

Comment: Is there a way to obtain tags internally in the pipeline?

Comment: If you don't have jq but you have docker you can replace "jq" by "docker run --rm -i imega/jq"

Comment: @Nicolas Repinster you need to wrap around the command because you're using colons... According to the doc here: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/script.html#use-special-characters-with-script.

Answer (score 8):

You can do this very easily without long script code.

```
script:
  - git fetch --tags
  - git tag --list | sort -V | tail -n1
```

assign in variable ${VER} with your version:

```
script:
  - VER=$(git tag --list | sort -V | tail -n1)
```

Comment: Unfortunately, git command is not guaranteed to be run successfuly if you're using a docker runner.

Comment: @Annahri in that case, try to run it in the `build` step, which definitely has `git`, then export to external build file and use it in other step

Answer (score 2):

Without GitLab API, you can just use:

```
script: 
  git describe --abbrev=0 2>/dev/null || echo ''
```

assign in variable to compare with your version:

```
script: 
  last_v=$(git describe --abbrev=0 2>/dev/null || echo '')
```

Return last tag or empty string if no tag found (using `2>/dev/null` to hide error code)

### ⚠️  Warning:

After test, leaving Tag message blank creates a lightweight tag, and command above will not work.

Comment: does not work for tags created using GitLab UI

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, `git` is not available in the `docker:dind` image.

I therefore like to keep versions in a file `.version`, next to the git tag.

e.g.:

```
__version__ = '0.8.1'
```

This allows to read the version using simple `cat` in Gitlab CI:

```yaml
image: docker:dind

variables:
  DOCKER_DRIVER: overlay2
  DOCKER_TLS_CERTDIR: "/certs"

services:
  - docker:dind

build and push latest:
  stage: build
  script:
    # get latest version from file, so we do not need to install git
    - VERSION=v$(cat .version | cut -d"'" -f 2)
    - docker login --username gitlab-ci-token --password $CI_JOB_TOKEN $CI_REGISTRY
    - docker build --pull --tag $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE:$VERSION .
    - docker push $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE:$VERSION
  only:
    - master
```

Note that the specific syntax I use in the `.version` file is associated with [python-semantic-release](http://python-semantic-release.readthedocs.io/), which allows to automate semantic versioning. The above would work with or without semantic-release. Semantic-release simply helps to maintain versions in `.version` file and git tags.

The corresponding `setup.cfg` looks as follows:

```
[semantic_release]
version_variable: .version:__version__
upload_to_pypi: false
branch: master
hvcs: gitlab
build_command: echo Skipping wheel build
```

Semantic-release can be used locally (run `semantic-release publish`), or integrated into the CI. It also does not matter whether the project is Python or another language.